# Create SPList Metadata

Tags: list, metadata, date-time

I want to give a SPLists a Expiry Date so they are later deleted through a timerjob.
The value is set by the user when they create a list through my functioning visual webpart.

Is it possible to give a List this value or do I have to give each SPListItem?

Comment: you want to delete the items in the list or the whole list?

Comment: The whole list. Right now I see only two solutions. Either add expirydate to lists description or have a column for each listitem with the same expirydate. It works but its ugly.

Comment: To add an expiry date to the item in a list is easy - you could do that with OOTB features. Deleting the list on the other hand seems somewhat more complex - no idea comes to mind. Could you live by using folders inside a main lib that won't be deleted? That way you should be able to use retention policies.

Comment: Deleting the list is easy. Im using a timerjob to iterate through lists on a specific webapp and compairing todays date with ExpireDate-value, then deleting all lists that is expired.

Comment: So your problem isn't deleting the list (you use a timer job). It is "how to mark the list for deletion / how to recognize which list to delete". Ok, forget my suggestion about retention polices... seems you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many SharePoint objects have a Property collection. Lists do not directly, but you can use `list.RootFolder.Properties` and there are methods for Add, Delete, Get, and SetProperty. There's an example here: http://www.novolocus.com/2012/07/23/getting-and-setting-properties-in-sharepoint/

Comment: This looks very promising. I will implement it and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

a simple method would be to have a hidden date field associated with the default document type in the list and to set that at a specific date e.g. 25th December 1970 for example.  It could then be easily used as the identifier when you want to remove the list.

If you want to have a hidden field like this added to the type, you'll need to set the 'Allow Management of Content Types' to 'Yes' and then you can either add a new column to that and set it as hidden by default or create a new column and again set it to hidden.  Importantly it wouldn't be visible in any way to end users etc. but would be useful programmatically.

Hope this is a useful alternative.  Alan C.

Comment: This was how i temporarily solved it at first. Thanks for your assistans.